# OAuth Implementation in ASP.NET Core using Swagger

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want to implement OAuth in my web application and for that I added the following code in my `startup.cs`

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CombiTime API v1.0", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:4200/login"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:4200/connect/token")
                        }
                    }
                });
                c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeOperationFilter>();

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference{
                                Id = "Bearer", //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            }
                        },new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });

            return services;
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");
                c.DocumentTitle = "Title Documentation";
                c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                c.OAuthClientId("combitimeapi_swagger");
                c.OAuthAppName("Combitime API");
                c.OAuthUsePkce();
            });

            return app;
        }
```

and the `AuthorizeOperationFilter` Code is as follows :

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // Since all the operations in our api are protected, we need not
            // check separately if the operation has Authorize attribute
            operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
            operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    [
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference {Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2"}
                        }
                    ] = new[] {"combitimeapi"}
                }
            };
        }
```

By using this code, I get an "Authorize" button on my swagger UI and when I click that button I am redirecting to my login page(front end based on angular). So I gave my `AuthorizationUrl` as `http://localhost:4200/login` and then when I am redirected to login  page, I login with valid credentials, I have used jwt token for login and for that I added the following code in my `startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

I want to redirect back to the swagger UI after I login with valid credentials but the problem is that I am being redirected to the dashboard after I login. Please help me or let me know what I am doing wrong.

The url that is being formed after I am redirected to login page from swagger is :

```
http://localhost:4200/login?response_type=code&client_id=combitimeapi_swagger&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:61574%2Foauth2-redirect.html&state=V2VkIEZlYiAxNyAyMDIxIDIyOjU3OjQ2IEdNVCswNTMwIChJbmRpYSBTdGFuZGFyZCBUaW1lKQ%3D%3D&code_challenge=mT0amBTJgczCZmNSZAYVfjzzpaTiGb68XlyR3RNHuas&code_challenge_method=S256
```

My front-end is running on port 4200.
My swagger is running on port 61574.
But I am not being redirected to swagger UI after putting in valid credentials
Please help me.

Comment: Anyone pls help ?

Comment: I don't know an answer, but I'm facing the same issue. I'm gonna offer a bounty as soon as the question is eligible for it.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Please refer to this link : https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=7e10acd8-f2d5-40b8-b669-376436214149 (This course is free when you login from microsoft emai-id). The course "Getting started with asp.net core and OAuth" has everything defined. It helped me and now I am able to redirect back. There is probably something that you might be missing as I was. :)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Also, the redirection does not work on HTTP , It works on HTTPS because the information that authorization server provides , our browser cannot catch the response and refuses when the connection is not secure. Make sure that you are running the IdentityServer on localhost over HTTPS.

Comment: This may help https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/ASPNET-Core-Swagger-UI-Authorization-using-IdentityServer4

Comment: Even able to redirect to swagger, because it refresh to swagger page the access token can not be set in request headers. in swagger when refresh the page authorization header will lost.

Answer (score 11):

First, let me add some details to your picture:

1. You have two applications, one with API (based on ASP.NET Core) and one with frontend UI (Angular, but it doesn't matter), and, it's important, with authorization/authentication functions.
2. You use .NETCore 3.1
3. You configure an authorization for swagger that means any call from swagger UI page will use given authorization parameters.

So, for API application we have to add a class that has helper methods configuring our swagger:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CombiTime API v1.0", Version = "v1" });

            c.AddSecurityDefinition(
                "oauth2", 
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://lvh.me:4201/connect/authorize"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://lvh.me:4201/connect/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                { "combitimeapi", "Demo API" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeOperationFilter>();

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement 
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference{
                                Id = "oauth2", //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            }
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
        });

        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");
            c.DocumentTitle = "Title Documentation";
            c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            c.OAuthClientId("combitimeapi_swagger");
            c.OAuthAppName("Combitime API");
            c.OAuthScopeSeparator(",");
            c.OAuthUsePkce();
        });

        return app;
    }
}
```

Please, pay attention to the `AuthorizationUrl` property and to the `TokenUrl` property. The `AuthorizationUrl` property should be pointed to our OAuth2 server authorization endpoint. Please, keep in mind that authorization endpoint and logon page are different endpoints. We could get all-known endpoints for our frontend application by visiting the url: `https://lvh.me:4201/.well-known/openid-configuration` in case our application uses ASP.NET Core with IdentityServer.

Next, `Startup.cs` of our API application should contain:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... some your code ...

    services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.ApiName = "combitimeapi";
            options.Authority = "https://lvh.me:4201";
        });

    // ... some your code ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ... some your code ...
    app.UseSwaggerDocumentation();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    // ... some your code ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Please, do not forget to add attribute `[Authorize]` to all your controllers, because your `AuthorizeOperationFilter` assumes that's done.

Let's look for required changes for our frontend & authorize part. You should configure some certain things, like:

1. CORS policy
2. Awailable API clients (one is your Angular UI and another one is API application)
3. Awailable API resources
4. Authentication & authorization methods

The class `Startup.cs` should contain:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... some your code ...

    services.AddCors(policies => {
        policies.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
    });

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
            options.Clients.AddIdentityServerSPA("forntend", cfg => {});
            options.Clients.AddNativeApp("combitimeapi_swagger", cfg => {
                cfg
                    .WithRedirectUri("https://lvh.me:5001/oauth2-redirect.html")
                    .WithScopes("combitimeapi");
            });
            options.ApiResources.AddApiResource("combitimeapi", cfg => {
                cfg.WithScopes("combitimeapi");
            });
        })
        .AddApiResources();

    services
        .AddAuthentication(
            x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
    // ... some your code ...
}
```

I use here `.AddIdentityServerJwt()` instead of your's `.AddJwtBearer(...)` because I don't have your keys and other specific options.

The frontend application is configured to use ports 4201 for HTTPS and 4200 for HTTP, the API application is configured to use ports 5001 for HTTPS and 5000 for HTTP.

Now you can run both applications and go to the page `https://lvh.me:5001/index.html` and press the button 'Authorize' to get a dialog like: [image: auth dialog]

Enter you secret, mark scope and press 'Authorize' and, after you authenticate yourself you will get: [image: auth dialog]

If you do not get a successful result, please check log of the frontend application, usually it contains error that could help you to find out a problem.

Hope text above will help you.

Comment: when I am following this, I am unable to hit any of the API on the swagger UI.. where does the access token that I received from the authrization server go ? The main purpose of doing it in the swagger is to hit any API after the authentication from IdentityServer. But that is not working.. :(

Comment: I assumed authorization was added to API application, but it wasnt clear from my explanations so I added it explicitly to `Startup.cs` into `Configure(...)` and `configureServices(...)` methods of API application

Comment: You are also not matching the IDs of the Security Definition with the Security Requirement or AuthorizeOperation filter. Please, check the details in my answer to solve that part :)

Comment: @NPinheiro Thank you for a comment, I did change `OAuth2` to `oauth2` before so they are match, but didn't noticed one more place.

Comment: When I am using Authorization code flow, I don't have access to a client secret, how to get past this? I can get it to work on Postman with just the PKCE flow, get the token and authorize the api but can't do it with swagger since it always asks for a client secret

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the OAuth Web-site the case is described as *Per-Request Customization*

> ### Per-Request Customization
>
> Often times a developer will think that they need to be able to use a
> different redirect URL on each authorization request, and will try to
> change the query string parameters per request. This is not the
> intended use of the redirect URL, and should not be allowed by the
> authorization server. The server should reject any authorization
> requests with redirect URLs that are not an exact match of a
> registered URL.

> If a client wishes to include request-specific data in the redirect URL, it can > instead use the “state” parameter to store data that will be included after the > user is redirected. It can either encode the data in the state parameter itself, or use the state parameter as a session ID to store the state on the server.

I hope that helps you in your quest.

Source: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-registration/

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one problem with the Startup code, more properly in the `AddSwaggerGen`.

**Configuration of the Identity Provider:**

Independently of the redirect, are you able to get an access token, or are you getting some kind of error, for example in the request or in the Identity Provider itself?

Please note that the client configuration that you provide in Swagger must match the configuration in the Identity Provider. You seem to be following [Scott Brady's example](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration); we can observe that all his [Swagger's startup configuration](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration/blob/master/Api.Swashbuckle/Startup.cs) follows the information he has in the Identity Server ([here](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration/blob/master/IdentityServer/Config.cs)).

**Set the token in the calls to the API:**

Moreover, even if you are getting the token, I think you are not setting it in the subsequent calls from Swagger to the API itself.

The `AddSecurityDefinition` and the `AddSecurityRequirement` or the `AuthorizeOperationFilter` typically mention at least one scheme with the same identifier, since the first method defines the way that Swagger is authenticating and the second/third define the way that the calls to the API are authenticated (so, they must reference each other). However, you are using different IDs in all the three methods - *"OAuth2"*, *"Bearer"* and *"oauth2"* -, so none of them is linked.

I don't fully know your application, but I believe you could actually be using only one of the `AddSecurityRequirement` or the `AuthorizeOperationFilter`, since they are both specifying security requirements. The most important would be to reference the ID of the *SecurityDefinition* (in your case, *"OAuth2"*).

Scott's example, in fact, [only uses the `AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter`](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration/blob/master/Api.Swashbuckle/Startup.cs#L46) and uses [the same ID for the `OpenApiSecurityScheme`](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration/blob/master/Api.Swashbuckle/Startup.cs#L90) that was [previously registered in the `AddSecurityDefinition`](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Swagger-Integration/blob/master/Api.Swashbuckle/Startup.cs#L29) - in his case, *"oauth2"*, but any name/string could be used.